# Why this expression related to algorithm cost has this result?

Tags: algorithm

Hi and sorry for my bad English.
I'm studying computer science and I didn't understand why this expression (in the image) has this result.

[image: Tmedio is the "medium", "arithmetic mean" cost of a linear search algorithm]

Tmedio is the "medium" cost of a linear search algorithm, according to my mind and to the definition of summatory, if for example n = 4, the result should be like: (1/4)*(1+2+3+4)... What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum of first n numbers is n*(n+1)/2. Hence you get (1/n) * n * (n+1)/2 = (n+1)/2.

See the wiki page related to this identity here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF